# Nested react-router: did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm setting up nested routes within React-Router 1.0.0-rc3. Whenever I try to access one of the nested routes it throws an error: "Warning: Location "cars/family-cars" did not match any routes".

Here is a mockup:

[image: Routing (site) structure]

This is my routes:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />

  <Route path="categories" component={CategoriesPage} />

  <Route path="categories/:slug" component={CategoryPage}>
    <Route path=":slug" component={ProductTypePage} />
    <IndexRoute component={CategoryPage} />
  </Route>

  <Route path="*" component={AppNotFound} />
</Route>
```

Component:

```
CategoryPage = React.createClass({
  renderNavLinks(type) {
    return (
      <li key={type.slug}>
        // "type.parent" is a category name, e.g.
        // <a href="http://www.myshop.com/categories/cars/family-cars">Citroën</a>
        <Link to={type.parent + "/" + type.slug}>{type.name}</Link>
      </li>
    );
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.data.category[0].name}</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            { R.map(this.renderNavLinks, this.data.productTypes) }
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <section>
          {this.props.children}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: path="categories/:slug"  it's params of your component not a link so you have to first declare your Route in your Routes section so you have iterate the loop which you are doing in category page and register Route

Comment: @DhavalPatel Thanks, but how should I declare a route with a dynamic part (I mean _:slug_)?  If I add this: `<Route path="categories/:slug/:slug" component={ProductTypePage} />` before the "nested section" URLs like _www.myshop.com/categories/cars/family-cars_ will work only called directly (e.g. when you copy and paste URL into your browser).

Comment: Ahhh.. I have already  implemented in my project let me answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD:**

I reread your error-message:

"Warning: Location "cars/family-cars" did not match any routes".

Are you sure your Link goes to "/categories/cars/family-cars" and not just to "/cars/family-cars"?

Try to fix your link like this:

```
<Link to={"/categories/" + type.parent + "/" + type.slug}>{type.name}</Link>
```

**Original answer:**

It seems that the problem lies somewhere else, because when I try to downgrage router to 1.0.0-rc3, everything is working fine with these configs:

Routes:

```
<Route path='/' component={ConnectedApp}>
  <IndexRoute component={ConnectedDetails} />
  <Route path='wishlist' components={ConnectedWishlist} />
  <Route path='categories/:details' component={ConnectedDetails}>
    <Route path=':edit' component={DetailsEdit} />
    <IndexRoute component={DetailsView} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Sidebar:

```
<div className='sidebar'>
  <Link activeClassName='sidebar-link_active' className='sidebar-link' to='/categories/lol/wut'>
    Persoonlijke gegevens
  </Link>

  <Link activeClassName='sidebar-link_active' className='sidebar-link' to='/categories/lol'>
    Verlanglijst
  </Link>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, you were right, it is not the react-router fault :( It's data-management in Meteor.js.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented like

Index.js is my entry point of application which contain below mentioned code

```
 fetchData(config.url+'/Tasks.json?TenantId='+config.TenantId).then(function(items)
{
    var TaskData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items.json.Tasks));
    var Data=[];
    Object.keys(TaskData).map(function(task){
        if(TaskData[task].PageName !=='' && TaskData[task].PageUrl !=='')
        {
            Data.push({PageName:TaskData[task].PageName,path:TaskData[task].PageName+'/?:RelationId',PageUrl:TaskData[task].PageUrl});
        }
    });

    Data.push({PageName:'ContainerPage',path:'/ContainerPage/?:RelationId',PageUrl:'./pages/ContainerPage'});

        var routes=require('./routes')(Data);
        Router.run(routes,function(Handler){
        React.render(<Handler />,document.getElementById('root'));
    });

   }).catch(function(response)
{
    showError(response);
});
```

over here I have created one Data array which can contain the Routes details and I have passed those array in my route.js file which is creating Route of passed data so my route.js file contain below mentioned code

```
 export default (data =>
  <Route name="App" path="/" handler={App}>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={require('./pages/PageNotFound')} />
        </Route>
{ data.map(task =>
  <Route name={task.PageName} path={task.path}  handler={require(task.PageUrl)}>
  </Route>
    ) }
</Route>
);
```

hope this may help you :)